# How to make a lookup-table in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I want to create a table in *cassandra*, that is used as a lookup table. I have a lot of urls in my database and want to store ids instead of the urls-strings. So my approach is, to store the urls in a table with two columns: `id` (int) and `url` (text).

My problem is, that I need an index for the *url* field and also for the id field.

The *first index* is used during progressing new ulrs (so find an `id` for an url in the database) and the *second index* is use during displaying data (get the `url` for an id).

How can I implement that in *cassandra*?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating 2 separate tables for this:

```
CREATE TABLE id_url (id int primary key, url text);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE url_id (url text primary key, id int);
```

Inserts to these tables should be done with a batch:

```
BEGIN BATCH
    INSERT INTO id_url (id, url) VALUES (1, '<url1>');
    INSERT INTO url_id (url, id) VALUES ('<url1>', 1);
APPLY BATCH
```

Comment: So, the question for me is, is it better to create a second table or a second index?
What would you suggest?

Comment: Depends on you to decide which is better for you. You can read on both topics. https://pantheon.io/blog/cassandra-scale-problem-secondary-indexes and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136640/why-does-cassandra-recommend-against-creating-an-index-on-high-cardinality-colum

Comment: Also worth mentioning that if you have two different tables, in order to get the id you will need to know the full URL. Using indexes you can query using LIKE. In order to do this you need to create the index with different options. This reading will also help http://www.tsoft.se/wp/2016/08/12/sql-like-operation-in-cassandra-is-possible-in-v3-4/

Comment: Personally, I'd go with 2 tables because of better visibility of the data.

Comment: @Horia There is no LIKE support in the Cassandra CQL SELECT statement for standard indices and I definitely wouldn't recommend anyone uses SASI indices in production. They are very experimental and there are a number of well documented bugs associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE urls_table(
   id int PRIMARY KEY,
   url text
   );
```

and then create an index on the second column:

```
create index urls_table_url on urls_table (url);
```

Your first query is satisfied since you're querying over partition key. The second one is satisfied since you created an index on url column.

Comment: Please note, that using secondary index is not advised on columns with high cardinality. See [this page](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useWhenIndex.html#useWhenIndex__when-no-index) for explanation.